# Existing sites and changing of site definitions

Tags: site-definition

If I change a site definition for a SharePoint 2010 installation, for example by adding a web part, will this affect existing sites?

Or would I have to loop through the sites and update the existing sites?

I though that this had changed between SP 2007 and 2010, but maybe that was just for content definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to consider here is that changes to *actual site definitions* should not be made where the site definition is in use i.e. sites have been created from it. What this means in practice is that you need to use a technique such as [feature stapling](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/05/feature-stapling.html) to add a web part to a site.

As I mention in that article, feature stapling itself won't help you with existing sites - you'll need to loop through and activate the feature on those separately. PowerShell (and careful planning) is typically used here these days.